# Dynamically place a view in a relativeLayout horizontally

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to place image and text below that image in a horizontalSrollView. For this i am using a relativeLayout inside horizontalSrollView. now if I add view to relativeLayout it is placed one over another.
below is my code
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
          {
                              docName= new TextView (con);

```
                         doc_Name=doctors.get(j).getDoc_name();
                         appendLog("docName");
                         docName.setText(doc_Name);
                         docName.setId(111);
                       //new ImageLoadTask(doctors.get(j),imageView,context).execute(null, null);    

                        docLinearLayout.addView(docName);
                     }
```

My XML code

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the android:layout_below = "@id/PREV_ID"
In xml it would look like this for example, if it should be after an item before (For compatibility there is toRightOf, actually toEndOf would be enough)

```
        android:layout_toEndOf = "@id/TopBarLogo"
        android:layout_toRightOf = "@id/TopBarLogo"
```

If you want to do it within java code you should find the method name in here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

I hope this helps, if not, let me know :)

Happy coding and good luck :)

John

Comment: how would I get an ID of previous view. And in case of placing first view how would I align it.

Comment: if this is all your layout shell do, maybe using the Linear Layout would be more fitting. Then you do not need to care about this at all...
you could store the IDs in an additional array for example

Comment: LinearLayout places one image then name then image then name.... That is the reason I want to use RelativeLayout